# How can I pass a dictionary as a parameter in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I pass a dictionary object to another function? The code below:

```
Sub aaa(dict As Object)
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
...
process dict 
End Sub

Sub process(dict As Scripting.Dictionary)
    MsgBox dict.Count
End Sub
```

gives the compile error "User defined type not defined".

---

Also,

```
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

works, but

```
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
```

gives "User defined type not defined".

I'm using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use `CreateObject` you are binding the object at run-time (ie, late binding).  When you use `As Scripting.Dictionary` the object is bound at compile-time (ie, early binding).

If you want to do early binding you will need to set a reference to the correct library.  To do this, go to Tools --> References... and select "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"

Comment: Where is this "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" in Excel 2016?

Answer (score 6):

To avoid the error add the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (in Tools -> References).
Simplified example:

```
Sub test_dict()
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Call process(dict)
End Sub

Sub process_dict(dict As Scripting.Dictionary)
    MsgBox dict.Count
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

I would revise this answer to use late binding only, and use an object parameter:

```
Sub aaa(dict As Object)
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
...
process dict 
End Sub

Sub process(dict As Object)
    MsgBox dict.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It's not clear what that new answer brings. You say you would use Late Binding only, but don't say why.

Comment: Code is more reusable in new situations without undue references which can interfere with portability. Some libraries are not identical versions and not always found on another system late binding just keeps options open and less potential problems between releases, if you don't need intellisense.

Comment: If the library isn't on the other system, late-binding is going to break anyway. The `Scripting` library is pretty ubiquitous, and hasn't changed version in a *long* time. Declaring as `Object` will force late-bound calls to the object, which will be slower. You won't get Intellisense, and you won't get compile-time error checking. There are sometimes valid uses for late-bound libraries, but `Scripting.Runtime` is most definitely not one of them.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library for your macro to be able to recognize the types.
Goto Tools->References and check for Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Answer (score 1):

After you adding the "Tools->References->Microsoft Scripting Runtime" 
try this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim myLocalDictionary As New Dictionary
    myLocalDictionary.Add "a", "aaa"
    myLocalDictionary.Add "b", "bbb"
    myLocalDictionary.Add "c", "ccc"

    Call testPassDictionary(myLocalDictionary)

End Sub

Sub testPassDictionary(myDictionary As Dictionary)
    MsgBox myDictionary.Count
End Sub
```